# Formatting book for ebook in Sublime Text. What tools are there?

Tags: html, sublimetext2, kindle

I have about 800 pages of text to format. Catch is, it was all transferred from image via OCR. There are hardly any typos/subbed characters, but lots of weird format/indentations.

I'm doing the HTML formatting in SublimeText, and was wondering if there's any tools that will make this go faster, such as:

-is there a way for me to select a block of text, and have ST put paragraph tags around it?

-easy way to preview the HTML file?

..any other plugins or tricks?
I'm relatively new to both HTML and SublimeText, so thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

If you're new to sublime and don't have package control installed, do it now as a first thing. This allows you to extend sublime with awesome plugins:
https://sublime.wbond.net/installation

Now let's get started:

To get rid of most of the formatting errors, I would suggest to use sublime's regex search and replace function (so you don't have to do it all manually). Read on about it here:
https://docs.sublimetext.io/guide/usage/search-and-replace.html

Next, to wrap a selection into an HTML tag, follow the instructions here (not sure if this comes implemented in sublime, or if you have to install Emmet plugin for that):
https://coderwall.com/p/d1qphg

As an easy way to preview the HTML file, I recommend the LiveReload plugin. This is especially helpful so you don't have to reload the page all the time:
https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/LiveReload

Last, I would suggest to install something like a spellcheck plugin for sublime, but this is your choice:
https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Dictionaries